# Not able to pass prop from vue 3 component to vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Am passing the prop from vue 3 to vue 2 as follows. It works if both components are vue 2.But I need to pass the prop from vue 3 to vue 2.

In vue 3 component

```
<v2-components :name="userName"></v2-components>
```

Vue 2 component prop is defined as follows. But not receiving the prop in vue2 component.Is there any solution to this?

```
export default {
  name: 'App',


  props: {
    name: {
      type: String
    },
  },
```

Comment: Which exact version of Vue are you using? Without a really complex setup (which I doubt is the case) you shouldn't be able to run both Vue2 and Vue3 on the same page. But do note that Composition API syntax (often conflated with Vue3) can be used in Vue2 (`^2.7`), and Options API syntax (often conflated with Vue2) can be used in Vue3.

Comment: Your source code is not enough to clarify the problem. The export block is valid for both v2 & v3. Please show more code and consider to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)